# How to disconnect usb programmatically on Raspberry PI pico?

Tags: c, usb, raspberry-pi-pico, disconnect

I need the equivalent for the pico as `Serial.end()` is for an arduino, any ideas?

Project info:

- My pico waits for the usb connection to come alive (computer listening through stty, cat etc.)
- captures an image from a camera
- writes the image directly to a file on my pc

My terminal is waiting for more data until I unplug the cable. When I plug it back in I can go over the process again.

On an arduino I can programmatically call `Serial.end()` to stop the transfer (closing the terminal on my pc) and reconnect it with `Serial.begin()` in a loop and get the next image by calling stty again without all the unplugging.

I tried calling `stdio_usb_init()` again, looked in `stdio.h` for appropriate functions but found none?

I can force to stop listening to the port as well, then detect this on the pico and start over without unplugging the usb cable but this causes my port to hang after a while. ('never' happens with `Serial.end()` on an arduino)

Comment: Even though it sounds like X-Y problem, check this out: https://superuser.com/questions/1707773/how-to-turn-usb-connected-device-on-and-off-in-linux

Comment: Thanks for helping, I edited my post. I indeed also succeeded in aborting the serial port listener but this sometimes hangs my port (reboot of pc needed)